# Logic on looping and condition in dictionary

Tags: vba, excel

I am looping an dictionary and outputting it to activesheet the first 2 pictures then create additional sheet for the next two and so forth. Only want 2 pictures on each sheet depending on how many pictures maybe in the dictionary. I'm needing help on the logic as i'm unsure how to code the loop to only put 2 pictures after adding the first 2 to the active sheet.

Heres the code:

```
Dim PictureFilename As Variant
Dim FileList As Dictionary
....
For Each PictureFilename In FileList
    i = i + 1
    If i >2 then
        TabName = DefaultWorksheetNameAdder + " " + Format(Now(), "mm-dd-yyyy")
        PicWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=PicWorkbook.Sheets(PicWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = "NewSheet"
        Set PicWorksheet = PicWorkbook.Sheets(PicWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

        'how to handle the next two without having to code i > 4 , i > 6 ect.?
    Else
        Set Photo = PicWorksheet.Shapes.AddPicture(CStr(PictureFilename), msoFalse, msoCTrue, 1, 1, -1, -1)
        Set pic = Nothing
        Set pic = Photo
        colPictures.Add pic
    End If
Next
```

Comment: What is your dictionary object?

Comment: @Brian FileList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mod` is your friend here.  I restructured your code some, but this should give you what you need:

```
Dim PictureFilename As Variant
Dim FileList As Dictionary

i = 0

For Each PictureFilename In FileList
    i = i + 1

    If i > 2 And i Mod 2 = 1 Then
       TabName = DefaultWorksheetNameAdder + " " + Format(Now(), "mm-dd-yyyy")
       PicWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=PicWorkbook.Sheets(PicWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = "NewSheet"
       Set PicWorksheet = PicWorkbook.Sheets(PicWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    End If

    Set Photo = PicWorksheet.Shapes.AddPicture(CStr(PictureFilename), msoFalse, msoCTrue, 1, 1, -1, -1)
    Set pic = Nothing
    Set pic = Photo
    colPictures.Add pic
Next
```

Comment: Perfecto. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out `MOD`.

```
if i MOD 2 = 0 then...
```

`MOD` produces the modulo of a number.

0 MOD 2 is 0

1 MOD 2 is 1

2 MOD 2 is 0

3 MOD 2 is 1

4 MOD 2 is 0

Comment: so how would i use it in my code? when i need the first 2 pictures on active sheet then any next two will have to be on a different sheet

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
Dim PictureFilename As Variant
Dim FileList As Dictionary
....
i = 0
For Each PictureFilename In FileList '''Assuming you have a worksheet already.
    If i > 1 then
        TabName = DefaultWorksheetNameAdder + " " + Format(Now(), "mm-dd-yyyy")
        PicWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=PicWorkbook.Sheets(PicWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = "NewSheet"
        Set PicWorksheet = PicWorkbook.Sheets(PicWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        i = 0
    Else
        Set Photo = PicWorksheet.Shapes.AddPicture(CStr(PictureFilename), msoFalse, msoCTrue, 1, 1, -1, -1)
        Set pic = Nothing
        Set pic = Photo
        colPictures.Add pic
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: The thing is, i need the next two pictures on a new sheet, then the next two pictures on another sheet and so forth.

Comment: @ThisGuyJustNeedsHelp I know. That doesn't do it for you?

Comment: no because it only puts 1 picture on active sheet then jumps to i >1, then it only puts 1 pictures on each sheet it seems.

Comment: @ThisGuyJustNeedsHelp I made an edit. Sorry about that.